# collections keeps retrieving me "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I just cant seem to get the snapshot docs to show me the data from the server.

i have checked the collection. it is called `"creaciones"` without uppercase. I have 1 document and I have files written already. I've made no spelling mistakes whatsoever. I made this work before and now i cant.

```
db.collection('usuarios').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
        console.log(doc.data);
    });
    setupGrilla(snapshot.docs);

});

//Setup grilla
const setupGrilla = (data) => {

    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const grilla = doc.data();
        const creacion = `
    <div>
        <img src='jpg/${grilla.tipoCreacion}.png' alt='tipoCreacion'>
        <h2>${grilla.nombreCreacion}</h2>
        <img src='Imagenes/${grilla.nombreFoto}' alt='nombrefoto' class='imagen'>
        <span>piezas: ${grilla.piezas}</span>
        <span class='separador'></span>
        <span>tiempo: ${grilla.tiempo} minutos</span>
        <p>padre: ${grilla.ayuda} </p>
        <p class='puntos'>Puntos: ${grilla.puntos} </p>
    </div>
        `;
        html += creacion;
    });

}

//get Data
db.collection('creaciones').get().then(snapshot => {
        setupGrilla(snapshot.docs);
        console.log(snapshot.docs);
});
```

I expect it to show fetch the database data.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection('usuarios').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
        console.log(doc.data);
    });
    setupGrilla(snapshot.docs);

});
```

That code is just what I have tried before. No need to look into that because I don't have it written at the moment.

Comment: So is this the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setupGrilla` with a `snapshot.docs` argument, but `snapshot` is never defined.

Try `querySnapshot.docs` instead, or rename `querySnapshot` in `snapshot`.

You are also passing the wrong argument to your method

```
db.collection('usuarios').get().then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(doc){
        console.log(doc.data);
    });
    setupGrilla(snapshot); // <-- Here

});
```

Comment: it worked there. I also tried using querySnapshot but i got no positive results