# I cant fetch document.data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just cant seem to get the snapshot docs to show me the data from the server.

i have checked the collection. it is called "creaciones" without uppercase. I have 1 document and I have files written already. I've made no spelling mistakes whatsoever. I made this work before and now i cant.

ive tried using function "(querySnapshot){" but i got no positive results

```
//Setup grilla
const setupGrilla = (data) => {

    let html = '';
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const grilla = doc.data();
        const creacion = `
    <div>
        <img src='jpg/${grilla.tipoCreacion}.png' alt='tipoCreacion'>
        <h2>${grilla.nombreCreacion}</h2>
        <img src='Imagenes/${grilla.nombreFoto}' alt='nombrefoto' class='imagen'>
        <span>piezas: ${grilla.piezas}</span>
        <span class='separador'></span>
        <span>tiempo: ${grilla.tiempo} minutos</span>
        <p>padre: ${grilla.ayuda} </p>
        <p class='puntos'>Puntos: ${grilla.puntos} </p>
    </div>
        `;
        html += creacion;
    });

}

//get Data
db.collection('creaciones').get().then(snapshot => {
        setupGrilla(snapshot.docs);
        console.log(snapshot.docs);
});
```

I expect it to fetch the database data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already given you the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322565/11852431)

You are passing the wrong argument in your method

```
db.collection('creaciones').get().then(snapshot => {
        setupGrilla(snapshot);
});
```

And you can find the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)

Comment: thanks a lot :) You know, i tried that code before and it didnt work. Somehow it did now. Such a fast reply :D